# How do I exclude routing validation in nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

```js
// jwt guard

@UseGuards(AuthStrategyGuard)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService, private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
  @Post()
  async getIndex (@Body() body) {
    if (!body.user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('error auth');
    } else {
      const token = await this.authService.sign(body);
      return { token }
    }
  }
  @Post('auth')
  validating (@Body('token') token) {
    console.log(token, 'token');
    return {success: 1}
  }
  @Post('test')
  getTestIndex () {
    return {success: 1}
  }
}
```

> Here is the JSONWebToken validation logic

**I wanted to exclude the `@post ()` decorator from the JWT validation**

*what should I do?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by applying the guard only on the methods (endpoints ) you need to validate, in your case, it'll be: ( I assume you want to exclude the validation from the first route

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService, private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
  
  @Post()
  async getIndex (@Body() body) {
    if (!body.user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('error auth');
    } else {
      const token = await this.authService.sign(body);
      return { token }
    }
  }
  @UseGuards(AuthStrategyGuard)
  @Post('auth')
  validating (@Body('token') token) {
    console.log(token, 'token');
    return {success: 1}
  }
   @UseGuards(AuthStrategyGuard)
  @Post('test')
  getTestIndex () {
    return {success: 1}
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this idea using a custom decorator, using the `applyDecorators` method